# replacing image tag with background image in react-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have built my app using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

I have an image tab inside my component. It looks like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <div id="homePage">
    <div class="hero">
      <Image src="/images/welcome-page-pic.jpg" responsive />
    </div>
  </div>

);
```

Yes, the tag for image in this framework is "Image" not "img".

This will display the image but its not very responsive, so I did some playing around in dev tools and found a styling that worked if I used the image as a background image in css using the following styling:

```
.hero {
    background-image: url(/images/welcome-page-pic.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center right;
}
```

This, of course, requires removing the  tag and src altogether, but doing that just removes the image. If I try adding the styles to the HTML (or rather JSX) instead of the css, then the page just doesnt load at all. I also tried leaving the image and src and just adding the css minus the background-image styling - also a no go. Not sure if this is an issue with the framework or something stupid im doing. Thanks.

UPDATE: after playing around a bit more, I found that for whatever reason, my local host is not accepting the class "hero" into the nested div. If I add it in devtools manually, the image appears and responds how i want it to. Now the question is why the class isn't assigned to the div upon page load of the jsx.

Comment: Try adding this...  background-repeat: no-repeat property to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be className in react, from memory.